# using preventDefault in onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the code below doesn't seem to prevent the link from doing its thing?  I know I can just use `onclick="return false"`, but it should work with preventDefault, right?  I tried `onclick="function(e){this.preventDefault()}"` and `onclick="this.preventDefault()"`, but no love.

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <title>Test</title>  
    </head>  
    <body> 
        <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="function(e){e.preventDefault()}">Google Search</a>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I would say, it depends on the browser :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove `function(e){`. When you put `function(e){}` there, that means creating a function but not running it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/RnngR/

Do it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="event.preventDefault();">Google Search</a>
```

Comment: is `event` the standard name of an attr argument function?